# How to use notify() correctly to start new activity?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have recyclerview connected to my SecondActivity and in Adapter's onclick method I call a  method in my Second Activity. But that method needs to be static. I want to animate between slides, so when I click on one of the options of recyclerview screen should do slide_out_right animation onto third activity.
Following is code in Adapter

```
     holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String selectedOption = item.getSelectedOption;//item is object of Item class(class used to populate recyclerview)
            SecondActivity.startThirdActivity(selectedOption);
        }
    });
```

Following is the method in SecondActivity

```
public static void startThirdActivity(String recyclerSelectedOption) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString(MESSAGE_FROM_SECOND, recyclerSelectedOption);
    intent.putExtras(extras);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

}
```

Now as many of you will know that startActivity is a non-static method and I can't call it from static method. But I also can't call non-static method from static recycler view.
So I want to create a variable in my secondActivity and set it to null. And I want a method to be called when this variable is set with a selected option from recyclerList, which will be non-static and which can jump to ThirdActivity using startActivity() method.

I know it's a bit of a big question. Obviousely if you know of another way by which I can avoid doing all this and just animate directly from Adapter to ThirdActivity then let me know.
Thanks,
HyperCoder

Comment: Make `startThirdActivity` return the `intent` and then call `startActivity(...)` on the returned value inside your listener.

Comment: @hyperCoder Using static method like this is not at all recommended.

Comment: Jean that doesn't help me with overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);

Comment: because overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out); can't be called either from static method or from Adapter

Comment: Balu, I just tried alt+enter and went on doing stuff that android studio suggested. when android studio didn't have anything else I thpught of .notify() method. But that didnt work out either :(

Comment: @hyperCoder did you try using interface ?

Comment: Hey Balu, No I did not. I read it. I am still trying to figure out how. Can you give more clarification on that.

Answer (score 0):

Use interface.

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(String item);
}
```

Now adapter constructor will be

```
private final OnItemClickListener listener;
public CustomAdapterAdapter(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Now onclick listener pass selcted option

```
holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            String selectedOption = item.getSelectedOption;
            listener.onItemClick(selectedOption );
        }
    });
```

You have to implement `OnItemClickListener`  on `SecondActivity`

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(String item){
            startThirdActivity(item)
            }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm trying to implement it in my code.Just a bit confused how the variable in SecondActivity will be updated depending on user's choice

Comment: You are passing selectedOption string from onClick in adapter to Activity through interface

Comment: ohh. hmm.okay. I will definitely try interface as I like them and they seem more elegant. But for now to solve problem of                 overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.slide_in_left, android.R.anim.slide_out_right);
 implementing overridePendingTransition in ThirdActivity worked as per @Sir Codesalot

Comment: Ok Good. you got solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `context` from the `view` to `SecondActivity` like this:

```
SecondActivity.startThirdActivity(selectedOption, view.getContext())
```

And then use the context to start the activity like this:

```
context.startActivity(intent);
```

I believe you can call `overridePendingTransition` in `onCreate` of `ThirdActivit`

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried this, but it still doesn't help me with overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out); Because I can't call it from static method :(

Comment: I believe you can call `overridePendingTransition` in `onCreate` of `ThirdActivity`

Comment: Damn, it was that easy. That worked. I kept trying to use it in secondActivity and Adapter class. And neither was working